# Can't integrate NFTs pallet into latest version of substrate-contracts-node

Tags: substrate-contracts-node

I'm using the substrate-contracts-node as the base of my node. And I'm now trying to integrate the NFTs pallet into runtime and parachain-runtime.

I have managed to do this successfully with earlier version. It seems that the current version has changed the way that pallets are imported by migrating to crate version imports instead of git imports.

In the root Cargo.toml all pallets are imported like this:

```
pallet-aura = { version = "29.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-authorship = { version = "30.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-balances = { version = "30.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-nfts = { version = "25.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-message-queue = { version = "33.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-session = { version = "30.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-sudo = { version = "30.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-timestamp = { version = "29.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "30.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc = { version = "32.0.0" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "30.0.0", default-features = false }
```

I only added pallet-nfts. I used the highest version I could find on crates.io. Then I added pallet-nfts to the dependencies like this: `pallet-nfts = { workspace = true }` and I added the entries for pallet-nfts to `std`, `runtime-benchmarks` and `try-runtime`.

Then I added the Config implementation:

```
/// Configure pallet-nfts.
impl pallet_nfts::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type CollectionId = u32;
    type ItemId = u32;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type CreateOrigin = AsEnsureOriginWithArg<EnsureSigned<AccountId>>;
    type ForceOrigin = RootOrigin;
    type Locker = ();
    type CollectionDeposit = NftsCollectionDeposit;
    type ItemDeposit = NftsItemDeposit;
    type MetadataDepositBase = NftsMetadataDepositBase;
    type AttributeDepositBase = NftsAttributeDepositBase;
    type DepositPerByte = NftsDepositPerByte;
    type StringLimit = ConstU32<4096>;
    type KeyLimit = ConstU32<64>;
    type ValueLimit = ConstU32<256>;
    type ApprovalsLimit = ConstU32<20>;
    type ItemAttributesApprovalsLimit = ConstU32<30>;
    type MaxTips = ConstU32<10>;
    type MaxDeadlineDuration = NftsMaxDeadlineDuration;
    type MaxAttributesPerCall = ConstU32<10>;
    type Features = NftsPalletFeatures;
    type OffchainSignature = Signature;
    type OffchainPublic = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;
    // TODO: type WeightInfo = weights::pallet_nfts::WeightInfo<Runtime>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_nfts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type Helper = ();
}
```

which results in the following error:

```
    Checking trc-node-runtime v0.1.1 (/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/rust/trc-node/runtime)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_nfts::Event<Runtime>`
   --> runtime/src/lib.rs:271:1
    |
271 | // construct_runtime!(
272 | ||     pub struct Runtime {
273 | ||         System: frame_system,
274 | ||         RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip,
...   ||
284 | ||     }
285 | || );
    | ||_- in this macro invocation
...   |
    |
note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_nfts::Event<Runtime>`
   --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pallet-nfts-25.0.0/src/lib.rs:383:11
    |
383 |     pub enum Event<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
    |              ^^^^^
    = note: no field of an enum variant may have a dynamically sized type
    = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
    = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
    |
271 | &construct_runtime!(
    | +

error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>: frame_support::traits::tokens::currency::Currency<_>` is not satisfied in `pallet_nfts::Event<Runtime>`
   --> runtime/src/lib.rs:271:1
    |
271 | // construct_runtime!(
272 | ||     pub struct Runtime {
273 | ||         System: frame_system,
274 | ||         RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip,
...   ||
284 | ||     }
285 | || );
    | ||_- in this macro invocation
...   |
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `frame_support::traits::tokens::currency::Currency<AccountId>`:
              frame_support::traits::tokens::currency::reservable::WithName<NamedReservable, Id, AccountId>
              ()
note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_nfts::Event<Runtime>`
   --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pallet-nfts-25.0.0/src/lib.rs:383:11
    |
383 |     pub enum Event<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
    |              ^^^^^
    = note: no field of an enum variant may have a dynamically sized type
    = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
    = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
    |
271 | &construct_runtime!(
    | +
```

What is causing this and how can I solve it?